# Small question about exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X\sim exp(0.001)$ then:
$P(800<X<1200)=F_X(1200)-F_X(800)=1-e^{-1.2}-(1-e^{-0.8})=-e^{-1.2}+e^{-0.8}$ ??

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @user88595 - But how can $P$ be less then zero?

Comment: it's not: $$e^{-0.8} > e^{-1.2}$$

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you!! But how it can be: $0.14$?? It should be much higher, no? @user88595.

Comment: What makes you think it should be greater? Check probabilities that $X<800$ and that $X>1200$ to convince yourself your result is correct.

Comment: @user88595 - You right!
BTW: $$P(X>1000)=e^{-0.001\cdot 1000}=\frac1e$$?

Comment: Looks like it. Any number you throw at it will work as long as you do the correct calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Close, but for the sign: $F(x) = 1 - exp(-x/\beta)$. 
In your parameterization, $\beta = 1/0.001$ so that $F(x) = 1 - exp(-0.001x)$

Comment: What do you mean when you write: $exp(-x/\beta)$ ?

Comment: Why $1/0.001$? $\lambda=0.001$....

Comment: I edit my answer, now this OK?

Comment: It still doesn't make sense: How $P=0.14$? I think that something is wrong...

Comment: @Yoar: There is notational ambiguity in writing $\text{exp}(\alpha)$, since some people consider the parameter to be $\lambda$, where the density if $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, and some people use the parameter $\mu$, with density function $\frac{1}{\mu}e^{-x/\mu}$. This is unfortunately not the only place where the role of a parameter is ambiguous. It happens often with the gamma, and even with the normal. In this case, because of the size of the numbers involved, it seems clear that what is intended is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ with $\lambda=0.001$.